# I am using `eureka docker container` but it is giving faults

Tags: docker, dashboard, netflix-eureka

I am using `eureka` container but unfortunately it is not working properly.
**Docker-compose.yaml**

configserver:

```
image: 1.2.3.4:1234/configserver
container_name: configserver
ports:
- 8888:8888
volumes:
- /tmp/logs:/tmp/logs
env_file:
 - ./docker.env
```

eureka:

```
container_name: eureka
ports:
- 8761:8080
volumes:
- /tmp/logs:/tmp/logs
env_file:
 - ./docker.env
image: netflixoss/eureka:1.3.1
restart: always
depends_on:
- configserver
```

Logs of Container-

> WARN com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient:1570 [localhost-startStop-1]
>    [makeRemoteCall] Can't get a response from localhost:8080/eureka/v2/apps
>   ERROR com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient:1432 [localhost-startStop-1] [makeRemoteCall] Can't contact any eureka nodes - possibly a security group issue?
>   ERROR com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient:1033 [localhost-startStop-1] [fetchRegistry] DiscoveryClient_EUREKA/4ae83dcdde1a - was unable to refresh its cache! status = java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used different image. Instead of `netflixoss/eureka:1.3.1` I use `eureka`. It works for me.